# Get last 7 and next 7 days in date format in swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I am trying to fill an array of type `Date` with 15 values, today, the 7 days prior, and the next 7 days. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to get the date. I tried implementing it like this:

```
func setupDates(){
        //get date of 7 days prior to right now
        for i in 1...15 {
            //add a day per iteration
            //append date to date array
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hint: `addingTimeInterval(_:)`

Comment: @ElTomato Terrible hint. Not every date have 24 hours.

Comment: Or `date(byAdding:to:options:)`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest having a look at [`Calendar`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar)

It can be a little cumbersome, but generally has a lot of power to it

So you might do something like...

```
let anchor = Date()
let calendar = Calendar.current

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateStyle = .long
formatter.timeStyle = .long
for dayOffset in -7...7 {
    if let date = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: dayOffset, to: anchor) {
        print(formatter.string(from: date))
    }
}
```

*nb: This was a simple playground test*

Which will print something like...

```
October 1, 2021 at 10:22:05 AM GMT+10
October 2, 2021 at 10:22:05 AM GMT+10
October 3, 2021 at 10:22:05 AM GMT+11
October 4, 2021 at 10:22:05 AM GMT+11
October 5, 2021 at 10:22:05 AM GMT+11
October 6, 2021 at 10:22:05 AM GMT+11
October 7, 2021 at 10:22:05 AM GMT+11
October 8, 2021 at 10:22:05 AM GMT+11
October 9, 2021 at 10:22:05 AM GMT+11
October 10, 2021 at 10:22:05 AM GMT+11
October 11, 2021 at 10:22:05 AM GMT+11
October 12, 2021 at 10:22:05 AM GMT+11
October 13, 2021 at 10:22:05 AM GMT+11
October 14, 2021 at 10:22:05 AM GMT+11
October 15, 2021 at 10:22:05 AM GMT+11
```

*nb: Today is the 8th*
*nbb: Your question title says "date format", but you're just trying to fill an array with `Date`s.  The basic concept will work either way*